# Image preview not being shown in react

Tags: reactjs

I have trying to make a imagePreview in reactjs, however , due to some reasons its not being shown. i searched about it and people are using refs in it.
Can please someone tell me why we would need ref here and how to show the preview.
This is my full code.

```
import React from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      file: '',

    };


  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] })
  }

  onFormSumbit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.state.file)

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }

    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/upload', formData, config).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })

  }




  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <img src={this.state.file[0]} alt="preview" />
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSumbit}>
          <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} name="foo" />
          <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your render function:

```
render() {
    return (
      <>
        <img src={this.state.file} alt="preview" />
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSumbit}>
          <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} name="foo" />
          <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }
```

In `onChange` function, you are already assigning the [0]th element.

```
  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] })
  }
```

So I removed [0] from `<img src={this.state.file[0]} alt="preview" />`